# I Really need help used windows recovery partion for Installing ubuntu and only have 3.87 gib right now ay help?Thx?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

Yeah so I was installing Ubuntu and i used windows recovery partition as the Ubuntu place where I decreased the size not knowing what the partition did and now I am running low on space and it wont let me boot windows 8 And i cant boot VIA flash drive  or via Live CD to increase my partition  space I really need help Please of you can help because I'm new to Ubuntu I love it but I don't know  it might of messed up my laptop if I cant fix it. thanks :)

Comment: Why can't you boot via flash drive or live CD?

Answer (score 0):

So let me make sure I am getting this right, you tried to install Ubuntu but you reformatted the Windows recovery partition?

If you reformatted any part of the Windows partition, that data might as well be gone. If you would like to you can make a Windows 8 recovery flash drive. you can [Create a Windows USB recovery drive](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-usb-recovery-drive)

But I have a strange feeling that deleting the Windows 8 recovery partition isn't the problem, I am not very Windows 8 savvy but I know people do it on purpose to recover space. May I ask why a live CD or flash drive won't work?

I would recommend booting a live version of any Distro and use disk tools or Gparted to figure out what you resized. I know you said that wasn't possible but it may be your best bet aside from reinstalling everything.
The command `fdisk -l` may give us a better idea whats going on if you can get to terminal.